# Dropdown(list) ComboBox control field options C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox

I use a `ComboBox` `DropDown` to show a number of items that can be selected. I also use a default text "Select item". It works perfectly apart from the fact that once I picked an item from the list, I can select the text and remove it (using the backspace) so that the area for the selected item is blank (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A77aM.png)).

I would like to prevent this or, in case this is not possible, to have the default text shown again. The latter doesn't work so far, so I tried the `DropDownList` but then the background of the entire list becomes grey. If I then select `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable` in `DrawMode`, the background turns white again but also the font color becomes white (instead of black).

I found that I have to use `DrawItem` to change the layout but even that doesn't work. I simply want the same style as I indicated for `DropDown`. Does anyone know how to do this or where to find a similar question that has already been answered?

Comment: Have you searched for other questions on this site that might give you the answer? Also, if you use the C# tag, more people will see the question. just click the edit link in your question, and add the tag (text field at the bottom of the page).

Comment: I've been searching for 2 days now, but I can't find the right key words to find an answer and using all kinds of DrawMode and DrawItem options doesn't work either. This seems a very easy thing but I simply can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested solution did not do the trick but I found a workaround to the initial problem, which is the manual deletion of the ComboBox Text, so I'll just put it here in case someone else has the same problem. When using

```
MyComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I can set a restriction myself: if the text is blank, it should show the default text. If the typed text is equal to one of the item in the ComboBox, it should set the selectedItem equal to the typed text.

I also included `GotFocus` and `Leave` `EventHandlers`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?
You could also try setting the DropDownStyle to DropDownList and FlatStyle to Flat. This gives you a slightly different result.

```
private void InitialiseCombo(ComboBox combo)
{
    combo.Items.Clear();
    combo.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 3391200121, 3391200122 });
    combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    combo.Text = "Select Item";
    combo.KeyPress += combo_KeyPress;
}

void combo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I didn't completely work, but thanks anyways. I found a workaround for my specific problem.

Comment: Good to hear! I've been in the same position, it can be frustrating getting these things exactly the way you want!